# GoogleMaps not showing markers near the poles

Tags: android, google-maps, latitude-longitude

Using the googleMaps api, how do I make it so the user can pan and see all of the markers. Currently I can only see the first three (as in my map does not let me zoom past approx 82 degrees N).

```
override fun onMapReady(p0: GoogleMap) {
        mMap = p0
        
        val markerOptions = MarkerOptions()
        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions.position(LatLng(0.0, 0.0)))
        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions.position(LatLng(70.0, 0.0)))
        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions.position(LatLng(80.0, 0.0)))
        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions.position(LatLng(85.0, 0.0)))
        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions.position(LatLng(86.0, 0.0)))
        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions.position(LatLng(87.0, 0.0)))
        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions.position(LatLng(88.0, 0.0)))
}
```

I know this might get into some limitations about 2D projections at the poles, but is there any workaround to this

Comment: Some useful information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27107440/unable-to-set-a-latlngbounds-with-longitude-from-180-to-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Official Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/views):

> Maps SDK for Android represents the world's surface (a sphere) on your
> device's screen (a flat plane) using the Mercator projection. In the
> east and west direction, the map is repeated infinitely as the world
> seamlessly wraps around on itself. In the north and south direction
> the map is limited to approximately 85 degrees north and 85 degrees
> south.
>
> Note: A [Mercator projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection) has a finite width longitudinally but an
> infinite height latitudinally. We "cut off" base map imagery utilizing
> the Mercator projection at approximately +/- 85 degrees to make the
> resulting map shape square, which allows easier logic for tile
> selection.

More information you can find in answers for [Maximum Lat and Long bounds for the world - Google Maps API LatLngBounds()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11849636/6950238) question of  [Ryan Brodie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1095883/ryan-brodie) - it is about javascript, but ideas are the same.

Comment: Is there a way to use a projection other than Mercator?

Comment: @Edward in Google Maps - no. You can use [Google Earth](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.earth&hl=en) and [KML/KMZ files](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut) like in answers for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27058193/6950238) question. Probably you also can use [web version of Google Earth](https://earth.google.com/web/) via 'WebView' (I didn't test that).